# What is the equivalent of this Objective-C safe type casting expression in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, comparison

What is the equivalent of this expression:

```
if ([stream isKindOfClass:[OWTRemoteMixedStream class]]) {
    _mixedStream = (OWTRemoteMixedStream *)stream;
}
```

in Swift?

```
if (stream is OWTRemoteMixedStream) {
    // mixedStream = stream OWTRemoteMixedStream  
}
```

Comment: The cast (commented line), would be `mixedStream = stream as? OWTRemoteMixedStream`, but that woiuld make it optional, maybe an `if let` would have been better first. if `let stream = stream as? OWTRemoteMixedStream { self.mixedStream = stream }` ? It depends on how is defined `mixedStream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type checking operator is indeed `is` in Swift. However, if you want to check the type and also cast it in case the type is a match, you need to use optional casting, `as?`.

```
if let mixedStream = stream as? OWTRemoteMixedStream {
    // use mixedStream, which has the type OWTRemoteMixedStream
}
```